# Freemarker: Output comma separated list as an array

Tags: freemarker

I have a table that has a field that contains a comma separated list of order IDs. What I am trying to do is output each of those IDs separately so that I can use them to look up their corresponding order details in another table.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

So far I have tried:

```
    <#data Alerts_test_table as alerts_test>
    <#filter
    CUSTOMER_ID_=CONTACTS_LIST.CUSTOMER_ID_1>
    <#fields AD_ID_LIST>

    <#assign seq = ['${alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST}']>
    <#list seq?chunk(1) as row><#list row as cell>
    ${cell}
    </#list> </#list>

    </#data>
```

But this just outputs it as a line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have comma separated ID-s in `idsString`, and you want to iterate though the ID-s one by one. Then:

Data-model (with http://try.freemarker.org/ syntax):

```
idsString = "11, 22, 33"
```

Template:

```
<#list idsString?split(r'\s*,\s*', 'r') as idString>
  ${idString}
</#list>
```

However, in the template you have posted I see many strange things, so some ideas/pointers:

- Be sure that `alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST` is indeed a `String`, not a `List` that you can list directly, without `?split`-ing. If it's a `String`, then `'${alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST}'` is ultimately the same as `alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST`. In general, you never need an empty string literal and an `${}` in it. It's not useful (but sometimes harmful, as it converts non-string values to string).
- `?chunk(1)` is not useful. The point of `?chunk` is to slice a list to smaller lists, but if those smaller lists are to be 1 long, then you might as well just list the items of the original list.
- There are no such directives as `#data` and `#filter`. Is this some forked FreeMarker version?
- If the ID is a number that you need to pass to some API that expects a number, then you will have to convert it to number like `idString?number`.

Comment: Thank you for this!
So yes this is a version of Freemarker adopted by Oracle in one of their products.
I am now getting this error: Expected string. [alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST] evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence

I altered what you gave me a bit to replace the 11,22,33 with the field name that contains the values I'm pulling:
        <#list [alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST]?split(r'\s*,\s*', 'r') as idString>${idString} </#list>

Any thoughts on that error?

Comment: It's interesting to know that some Oracle project has forked FreeMarker to add custom directives... instead of contributing to the project so that they can plug in such things. Now they and you are stuck forever with the fork of some old FreeMarker version, judging from the old-style error message... Which Oracle product is this?

Comment: As of the error, `?split` applies to strings. If you add a `[]` around it, you make a sequence (a list) of length 1 from it, which can't be split, as it's not a string. Remove the `[]`, like `<#list alerts_test.AD_ID_LIST?split(r'\s*,\s*', 'r') as ...>`.

Comment: Ah that was the problem. Works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to figure out if the values that we're splitting out are even or odd?

Comment: You mean, to figure out if the value of the ID is odd or even? Like `id % 2 == 0` (which is true if even). Or `idString?number % 2 == 0`. (That it's the result of splitting is irrelevant.)

Comment: Sorry I meant that its index (i.e. where it falls in the list) is either even or odd. Not the value of the number itself. Basically I want to have an IF statement that outputs different HTML depending on whether the order id is first, third, fifth etc, or second, fourth, sixth etc.) in the list.

Comment: Since you seem to be stuck with some modified old version, I guess you will have to do something like `<#list ... as id>...<#if id_index % 2 == 0>odd item<#else>even item</#if>...</#list>`. On more up to date versions you could write things like `<#if id?is_odd_item>` or `${id?item_cycle('odd item', 'even item')}` (see http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html#ref_builtin_item_cycle).

Comment: Hey @ddekany, I posted another question with regards to the next phase of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46051640/6465941?sem=2. If you have time to take a look I would appreciate it.