# Freemarker: Removing values from list when they are missing from another table

Tags: function, loops, macros, freemarker

In field in a table I have a comma separated list of order IDs that I am splitting like this:

```
<#list alerts.AD_ID_LIST1?split(r'\s*,\s*', 'r') as idString>
```

What I need to do now is cross-reference each ID with another table to see if it *exists* in that table and that the ORDER_STATUS field does not have a value of deleted.

Then I need to output the new list of IDs with the missing and deleted order IDs removed so that I can loop through them based on their index. Can anyone give me an idea how to do this ? I was thinking a Macro or a function would be a good way to go but I'm not sure the best approach.

This is the code that executes afterward:

```
<#if idString_index % 2 == 0 && idString_has_next == false>

<!-- INCLUDE SINGLE CODE -->

<#elseif idString_index % 2 == 0 && idString_has_next == true>

<!-- Include LEFT SIDE CODE -->

<#else>

<!-- INCLUDE RIGHT SIDE CODE -->

</#if>
```

Comment: Things like this aren't meant be done in a template language. General purpose languages are much better fit for this. Templates meant to render data that's already "calculated". Anyway, if the order status table is a `Map` with the `ID`-s as keys, then you may get away with this purely using a template... but is it? (After even AD_ID_LIST1 was a string instead of a `List` there's no much hope though.) Can you add your own Java classes to add some helper functions at least?

Comment: Unfortunately this is HTML email, so this templating language is all I've got to work with. The Order Status table is used as a lookup table with the IDs as the lookup keys. I can add my own freemarker (not java) functions & macros (limitedly). The problem is that this is rendering a 2 column layout which needs different code for the left and right sides, and missing orders breaks the email altogether. Any thoughts on workarounds for this ?

Comment: That it's an email template should be irrelevant, as all kind of templates needs a backing "real" code that supplies the data to show. Anyway, if I understand, you can't do or request changes there.

Comment: It's still not clear how do you see the Order Satus table. Like can you do something like `orderStatusTable?api.get(idNumber).deleted`. Is this part of the problem solved?

Comment: As of the left-right thing, it should be something like this: `<#assign cellCount = 0><#list ... as id><#if shouldBeDisplayed><#assign cellCount++><#if cellCount % 2 == 1>...left...<#else>...right...</#if></#list><#if cellCount % 2 == 1>...blank right...</#if>`, where `shouldBeDisplayed` is of course need to be replaced with the real expression. Kind of ugly, but as far as FreeMarker has no list filtering, you can't use `?chunk(2)` here...

Comment: So the reason that I mention its an email template is that I am limited by the ESP's integration of Freemarker. I can get use an IF statement to determine  if the order is in the table or not or has been deleted. This seems like it would work but I guess the ESP doesn't support the ++ to increment :(

Comment: You can use `<#assign cellCount = cellCount + 1>` instead of `++` on old FreeMarker versions.

Comment: @ddekany - Thank you, that worked. Is there any way to check to see if ALL the ids in that string exist in the table and have a status of 'active' before looping through the list? If they all the values in the list are either missing or 'status=deleted' I need the template to cancel its execution.

Comment: There's no "special" way of doing it, just the obvious way... looping through them, and on the first negative case set a variable to `false`, and `#break` out of the loop. (Or for readability, this check can be put into a `#function` where you `#return false` on the first negative case.)

Comment: @ddekany - The issue I am having, is I can only seem to check if single IDs are missing from the table. I need to check if they are ALL missing. If there's even one that is present, the code needs to execute as normal. So in this case would you write a function outside of the #list directive?

Comment: Yes, certainly using a function is the cleanest solution.